# How to change Facebook username?

Tags: facebook, account-management

[image]

Do I have to re-register a new Facebook account to change my facebook.com/USERNAME?

Or are there any ways to change it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only change your Facebook username once. If you have already changed it then there is no way to change it again. You would have to setup a new account and claim a new username that way.

The option to change your username is in `Account Settings` > `Settings` > `Username`. If that option is not available then you cannot change your username.

[Taken from this Facebook support article.](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=162586890471598)

> **How do I change my username?**
>
> You can change your username from the [Settings](https://www.facebook.com/editaccount.php) tab of the Account
>   Settings page. Scroll down to "Username" and click "change." Then
>   follow the on-screen directions. Keep in mind you will only be able to
>   change your username once.

Comment: :( that's sad...

Answer (score 5):

You can only change your Facebook username **once**. It seems that you have done it already.

[image]